# Visual Studio has a different behaviour (without) using a breakpoint on log.LogInformation() with Azure Functions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, logging, azure-functions

I’m developing an Azure Function in Visual Studio 2019. I have a really strange behaviour when I debug it. The code is like the following:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MyNamespace {
    public static class MyClass {
        // ...

        static MyClass () {
            // ...
        }

        [FunctionName("...")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log) {

            log.LogInformation("XYZ");
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

If I put a breakpoint on the `log.LogInformation` statement, the application exits and Visual Studio automatically shows me this window error:

[image]

If I don’t put the breakpoint, or I put it after that statement, I see the `"XYZ"` string in the console of the Azure Function. What does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why the error happened. When over the log statement in debug mode, clicking <kbd>F11</kbd> caused the error to appear, but <kbd>F10</kbd> does not. I correctly see my strings logged to the Azure Function console.

Answer (score 1):

If you're debugging and you press F11, you're trying to step inside the code for which I believe is `log.LogInformation("XYZ")`. This prompts Visual Studio to open the source code located at `ScriptLoggingBuilderExtensions.cs` which is part of the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions`. To download a local copy of this source, you have to enable SourceLink in your Visual Studio by going to Options > Debugging > General > then checking the Enable Source Link Support

[image]

Comment: I didn’t know that. Thanks! Yes, I solved my problem using F10 instead of F11. I figured out it was something like that to cause the error.

Comment: @Pinecone please mark this as the answer so other people will take notice.

Comment: I already flagged my own answer since I found it myself hours before reading your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t have a solution for you but after thinking about the behavior this totally makes sense.
When you Just run the application, even in Debug mode, I don’t think Visual Studio has all of the code for every DLL in the process , hence why most of the time you get a “meta” version if you try to get the source code for some library.

In this case you have a breakpoint and may be trying to step into it and it’s crashing when trying to pull the source code.  Whereas if you just let it run, it doesn’t try to pull the source code and hence there is no error.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on `Enable Just My Code` in Visual Studio | Tools | Debugging | General.

[image: [](https://imgur.com/hiNJI.png)]